# Toolbar collapse on scroll with Drawer Layout, Coordinator Layout, and Fragments

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I'm trying to get the toolbar to collapse on scroll, but no matter what answer I follow I cannot seem to get it to collapse on scroll. The fragment that gets inflated in the FrameLayout is a View Pager if that makes a difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bluecadet.android.nasm.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/home"
                    />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.bluecadet.android.nasm.ui.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: you must have something to scroll in your layout. then only it will work

Comment: I have a fragment view pager loading in `@+id/container` that has a nested fragment with a scroll view. Will it not register with the nested fragment?

Comment: @Aashvi I'll take a look at the library, but I'm trying to do it without 3rd party libraries.

Comment: I think thats enough

Answer (score 0):

Well i am not talking about any thrid party library, it is included support design library. Your toolbar and image view have to be in CollapsingToolBarLayout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/abcd"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mtool"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```